# How can I download using a bash script from a CSV file with URLs?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv file of this format

```
http://nex.s3.amazonaws.com/tt/01.nc,d9aa8c1f1a6ea5f7fd52b0b9a02fc336
http://nex.s3.amazonaws.com/tt/02.nc,fe12be292a322c34bbec1a82bd55e77d
```

And I want to parse the CSV file, read the first column, and WGET each URL in this fashion. The 2nd column is of no use:

```
wget --user=NEXUSER --password="" http://nex.s3.amazonaws.com/tt/01.nc
```

So far, I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT='testfile.csv'
IFS=','

while read url sum
do
        echo $url
        echo $sum
        wget --user=NEXGDDP --password="" $url
done
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
cut -d, -f1 testfile.csv | xargs wget --user=NEXUSER --password=""
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you are missing is to redirect input to the loop from your file:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT='testfile.csv'

while IFS=, read url sum
do
        echo "$url"
        echo "$sum"
        wget --user=NEXGDDP --password="" "$url"
done < "$INPUT"
```

As a general rule, it's preferable to change `IFS` only when it is necessary; here, it's only the `read` command that needs an altered value. Also, be sure to quote parameter expansions unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Thank you...Makes sense. This was my first bash script.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
for url in `cut -d',' -f1 file.csv`; do
   wget --user=NEXGDDP --password="" "$url"
done
```